# Using named HttpClient from IHttpClientFactory in a custom client

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I know I'll get crucified for asking this question that has been asked a million times before and I promise you that I've looked at most of those questions/answers but I'm still a bit stuck.

This is a .NET Standard 2.0 class library supporting an ASP.NET Core 6 API.

In my `Program.cs` I create a named HttpClient like this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("XYZ_Api_Client", config =>
{
    var url = "https://example.com/api";
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
});
```

I have a custom client that will use this `HttpClient` and I create a singleton `MyCustomClient` in `Program.cs` so that my repositories can use it. The code is below. This is where I'm stuck as I'm not sure how to pass my named `HttpClient` into `MyCustomClient`.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new MyCustomClient(???)); // I think I need to pass the HttpClient to my CustomClient here but not sure how
```

And my `CustomClient` needs to use this `HttpClient` named `XYZ_Api_Client` to do its job:

```
public class MyCustomClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient _client;
   public MyCustomClient(HttpClient client)
   {
       _client = client;
   }

   public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
   {
      var result = await _client.GetAsync();
      return result;
   }
}
```

So I'm not sure how I can pass this named `HttpClient` into `MyCustomClient` in the `Program.cs`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can directly inject the `IHttpClientFactory` in you class, and then assign the named `HttpClient` to a property.

Register the factory and your custom client:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("XYZ_Api_Client", config =>
{
    var url = "https://example.com/api";
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
});

// no need to pass anything, the previous line registered IHttpClientFactory in the container
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyCustomClient>();
```

And then in you class:

```cs
public class MyCustomClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient _client;
   public MyCustomClient(IHttpClientFactory factory)
   {
       _client = factory.CreateClient("XYZ_Api_Client");
   }
   // ...
}
```

Or, you can pass the named instance when registering `MyCustomClient`

Register the factory and your custom client:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("XYZ_Api_Client", config =>
{
    var url = "https://example.com/api";
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
});

// specify the factory for your class 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyCustomClient>(sp => 
{
    var factory = sp.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var httpClient = factory.CreateClient("XYZ_Api_Client");
    
    return new MyCustomClient(httpClient);
});
```

And then in you class:

```cs
public class MyCustomClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient _client;
   public MyCustomClient(HttpClient client)
   {
       _client = client;
   }
   // ...
}
```

You can also do this:

```cs
// register the named client with the name of the class
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyCustomClient", config =>
{
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com/api");
});

// no need to specify the name of the client
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<MyCustomClient>();
```

What `AddHttpClient<TClient>(IServiceCollection)` does is

> Adds the IHttpClientFactory and related services to the IServiceCollection and configures a binding between the TClient type and a named HttpClient. The client name will be set to the full name of TClient.

You can find the full documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions-addhttpclient-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection)).

Comment: Thank you Alexandra for the super nice and detailed explanations!