# Typed HttpClient not correct when injected

Tags: asp.net-core

Stepping through the debugger I can have a new `HttpClient` instance but it's not the one with the added base url.

Service Interface

```
public interface IEmailer
{
    Task SendAsync();
}
```

Service Implementation

```
public class ApiEmail : IEmailer
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public SmtpEmail(HttpClient client)
    { 
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task SendAsync()
    {
        // FAILS HERE, NO BASE URL DEFINED
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("some/url/email");
    }
}
```

IService Helper Extension

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddEmailer(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<ApiEmailer>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://somewebemail.com/api/");
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailer, ApiEmailer>();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    ...
    builder.Services.AddEmailer();
    ...
    app.Run();
}
```

Controller

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEmailer _emailer;

    public WeatherForecastController(IEmailer emailer)
    {
        _emailer = emailer;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
    {
        await _emailer.SendAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddHttpClient` only works for transient services. You could configure a [named](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#named-clients) or [keyed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#keyed-services) client instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Would you have a link or example by chance?

Comment: [Named HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71908869/7450780)

Comment: Added links as requested.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for the links, after more reading it looks like it's following MS best practices to use transient HttpClients since the underlying HttpMessageHandler is pooled, addressing the resource issue? It looks like using a singleton would be for when you aren't using MS DI?

Comment: You can go either way: a singleton HttpClient is fine, too, if you add a pool lifetime. But if you want to set properties like BaseAddress, then you'd need your own instance. That said, if your service *can* be transient, then that would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing this

```
services.AddHttpClient<ApiEmailer>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://somewebemail.com/api/");
});
services.AddSingleton<IEmailer, ApiEmailer>();
```

to

```
services.AddHttpClient<IEmailer, ApiEmailer>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://somewebemail.com/api/");
});
```

Comment: This would work as far as the injection goes, but this does change the lifetime of `ApiEmailer` from singleton to transient.